# ResponsiveSlides Navigation Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using ResponsiveSlides for a photo slideshow on a page, and I cannot make the navigation button show up as they do on the website. Currently, the Previous and Next links appear below the slider as simple hypertext links. Here is how this is showing on the website:
[website-slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgCXE.png). See the Previous/Next buttons below image. Here is how I would like for this to look: [navigation-buttons-centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na72Z.png). I've tried so many different things and nothing is working, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that is being used:
HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="/wp/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/responsiveslides.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pager: false,
      nav: true,
      speed: 500,
      namespace: "rslides",
    });
  });

</script>
<link href="/wp/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/css/responsiveslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div class="rslides_container">
  <ul class="rslides rslides1 centered-btns centered-btns1">
    <li><img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''></li>
    <li><img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''></li>
    <li><img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''></li>
    <li><img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function($, window, i) {
  $.fn.responsiveSlides = function(options) {

    // Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      "auto": true, // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      "speed": 500, // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      "timeout": 4000, // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      "pager": true, // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      "nav": true, // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      "random": false, // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      "pause": false, // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      "pauseControls": true, // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      "prevText": "Previous", // String: Text for the "previous" button
      "nextText": "Next", // String: Text for the "next" button
      "maxwidth": "", // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      "navContainer": "", // Selector: Where auto generated controls should be appended to, default is after the <ul>
      "manualControls": "", // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      "namespace": "rslides", // String: change the default namespace used
      "before": $.noop, // Function: Before callback
      "after": $.noop // Function: After callback
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      // Index for namespacing
      i++;

      var $this = $(this),

        // Local variables
        vendor,
        selectTab,
        startCycle,
        restartCycle,
        rotate,
        $tabs,

        // Helpers
        index = 0,
        $slide = $this.children(),
        length = $slide.length,
        fadeTime = parseFloat(settings.speed),
        waitTime = parseFloat(settings.timeout),
        maxw = parseFloat(settings.maxwidth),

        // Namespacing
        namespace = settings.namespace,
        namespaceIdx = namespace + i,

        // Classes
        navClass = namespace + "_nav " + namespaceIdx + "_nav",
        activeClass = namespace + "_here",
        visibleClass = namespaceIdx + "_on",
        slideClassPrefix = namespaceIdx + "_s",

        // Pager
        $pager = $("<ul class='" + namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs' />"),

        // Styles for visible and hidden slides
        visible = {
          "float": "left",
          "position": "relative",
          "opacity": 1,
          "zIndex": 2
        },
        hidden = {
          "float": "none",
          "position": "absolute",
          "opacity": 0,
          "zIndex": 1
        },

        // Detect transition support
        supportsTransitions = (function() {
          var docBody = document.body || document.documentElement;
          var styles = docBody.style;
          var prop = "transition";
          if (typeof styles[prop] === "string") {
            return true;
          }
          // Tests for vendor specific prop
          vendor = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
          prop = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.substr(1);
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < vendor.length; i++) {
            if (typeof styles[vendor[i] + prop] === "string") {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        })(),

        // Fading animation
        slideTo = function(idx) {
          settings.before(idx);
          // If CSS3 transitions are supported
          if (supportsTransitions) {
            $slide
              .removeClass(visibleClass)
              .css(hidden)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(visibleClass)
              .css(visible);
            index = idx;
            setTimeout(function() {
              settings.after(idx);
            }, fadeTime);
            // If not, use jQuery fallback
          } else {
            $slide
              .stop()
              .fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
                $(this)
                  .removeClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(hidden)
                  .css("opacity", 1);
              })
              .eq(idx)
              .fadeIn(fadeTime, function() {
                $(this)
                  .addClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(visible);
                settings.after(idx);
                index = idx;
              });
          }
        };

      // Random order
      if (settings.random) {
        $slide.sort(function() {
          return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
        });
        $this
          .empty()
          .append($slide);
      }

      // Add ID's to each slide
      $slide.each(function(i) {
        this.id = slideClassPrefix + i;
      });

      // Add max-width and classes
      $this.addClass(namespace + " " + namespaceIdx);
      if (options && options.maxwidth) {
        $this.css("max-width", maxw);
      }

      // Hide all slides, then show first one
      $slide
        .hide()
        .css(hidden)
        .eq(0)
        .addClass(visibleClass)
        .css(visible)
        .show();

      // CSS transitions
      if (supportsTransitions) {
        $slide
          .show()
          .css({
            // -ms prefix isn't needed as IE10 uses prefix free version
            "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-moz-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-o-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out"
          });
      }

      // Only run if there's more than one slide
      if ($slide.length > 1) {

        // Make sure the timeout is at least 100ms longer than the fade
        if (waitTime < fadeTime + 100) {
          return;
        }

        // Pager
        if (settings.pager && !settings.manualControls) {
          var tabMarkup = [];
          $slide.each(function(i) {
            var n = i + 1;
            tabMarkup +=
              "<li>" +
              "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + n + "</a>" +
              "</li>";
          });
          $pager.append(tabMarkup);

          // Inject pager
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append($pager);
          } else {
            $this.after($pager);
          }
        }

        // Manual pager controls
        if (settings.manualControls) {
          $pager = $(settings.manualControls);
          $pager.addClass(namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs");
        }

        // Add pager slide class prefixes
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $pager.find('li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass(slideClassPrefix + (i + 1));
          });
        }

        // If we have a pager, we need to set up the selectTab function
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs = $pager.find('a');

          // Select pager item
          selectTab = function(idx) {
            $tabs
              .closest("li")
              .removeClass(activeClass)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(activeClass);
          };
        }

        // Auto cycle
        if (settings.auto) {

          startCycle = function() {
            rotate = setInterval(function() {

              // Clear the event queue
              $slide.stop(true, true);

              var idx = index + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

              // Remove active state and set new if pager is set
              if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
                selectTab(idx);
              }

              slideTo(idx);
            }, waitTime);
          };

          // Init cycle
          startCycle();
        }

        // Restarting cycle
        restartCycle = function() {
          if (settings.auto) {
            // Stop
            clearInterval(rotate);
            // Restart
            startCycle();
          }
        };

        // Pause on hover
        if (settings.pause) {
          $this.hover(function() {
            clearInterval(rotate);
          }, function() {
            restartCycle();
          });
        }

        // Pager click event handler
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs.bind("click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              if (!settings.pauseControls) {
                restartCycle();
              }

              // Get index of clicked tab
              var idx = $tabs.index(this);

              // Break if element is already active or currently animated
              if (index === idx || $("." + visibleClass).queue('fx').length) {
                return;
              }

              // Remove active state from old tab and set new one
              selectTab(idx);

              // Do the animation
              slideTo(idx);
            })
            .eq(0)
            .closest("li")
            .addClass(activeClass);

          // Pause when hovering pager
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $tabs.hover(function() {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function() {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

        // Navigation
        if (settings.nav) {
          var navMarkup =
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " prev'>" + settings.prevText + "</a>" +
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " next'>" + settings.nextText + "</a>";

          // Inject navigation
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append(navMarkup);
          } else {
            $this.after(navMarkup);
          }

          var $trigger = $("." + namespaceIdx + "_nav"),
            $prev = $trigger.filter(".prev");

          // Click event handler
          $trigger.bind("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $visibleClass = $("." + visibleClass);

            // Prevent clicking if currently animated
            if ($visibleClass.queue('fx').length) {
              return;
            }

            //  Adds active class during slide animation
            //  $(this)
            //    .addClass(namespace + "_active")
            //    .delay(fadeTime)
            //    .queue(function (next) {
            //      $(this).removeClass(namespace + "_active");
            //      next();
            //  });

            // Determine where to slide
            var idx = $slide.index($visibleClass),
              prevIdx = idx - 1,
              nextIdx = idx + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

            // Go to slide
            slideTo($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
              selectTab($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            }

            if (!settings.pauseControls) {
              restartCycle();
            }
          });

          // Pause when hovering navigation
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $trigger.hover(function() {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function() {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

      }

      // Max-width fallback
      if (typeof document.body.style.maxWidth === "undefined" && options.maxwidth) {
        var widthSupport = function() {
          $this.css("width", "100%");
          if ($this.width() > maxw) {
            $this.css("width", maxw);
          }
        };

        // Init fallback
        widthSupport();
        $(window).bind("resize", function() {
          widthSupport();
        });
      }

    });

  };
})(jQuery, this, 0);
```

CSS:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.rslides1_nav {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.rslides1_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.rslides1_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
}

.rslides1_nav:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.centered-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.centered-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.centered-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.rslides {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rslides_container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.centered-btns_nav {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.centered-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.centered-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
}

.transparent-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  /* Fix for IE6-9 */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  width: 48%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 91%;
}

.transparent-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.large-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000 url("themes.gif") no-repeat left 50%;
  width: 38px;
}

.large-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.large-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.centered-btns_nav:focus,
.transparent-btns_nav:focus,
.large-btns_nav:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.centered-btns_tabs,
.transparent-btns_tabs,
.large-btns_tabs {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.centered-btns_tabs li,
.transparent-btns_tabs li,
.large-btns_tabs li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  _float: left;
  *float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.centered-btns_tabs a,
.transparent-btns_tabs a,
.large-btns_tabs a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: inline-block;
  _display: block;
  *display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
}

.centered-btns_here a,
.transparent-btns_here a,
.large-btns_here a {
  background: #222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Comment: Can u create a jsfiddle for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this line under .rslides1_nav:

```
background: transparent url("themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
```

Try:

```
background: transparent url("http://responsiveslides.com/with-captions/themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
```

Or copy that image to your local and use whatever link would be appropriate.  I've been messing around with a fiddle, but it doesn't look quire right yet.  Hopefully, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2cg3q2ya/1/) can at least get you started

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `responsiveslides.css` and `theme.css`. After that you can download the image with the arrows from **[here](http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.gif)**. Or you can just change the background images path of `.centered-btns_nav` with the path from **[this](http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.gif)** link.

You can get the `responsiveslides.css` file from **[here](http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.css?v=1.5)**.

You can get the `theme.css` file from **[here](http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.css?v=1.5)**.

You also have to change the `namespace` property value from the plugin initialization to be:

```
namespace: "centered-btns"
```

See the working snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
   $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pager: false,
      nav: true,
      speed: 500,
      namespace: "centered-btns"
    });
 });
```

```css
http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.gif

/*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

html {
  background: #fff;
  }

body {
  color: #333;
  font: 14px/24px sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  _width: 700px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }

#wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

h1 {
  font: 600 28px/36px sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 0;
  }

h3 {
  font: 600 18px/24px sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  }

a {
  color: #222;
  }

.rslides {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.rslides_container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }

.centered-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
  }

.centered-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  }

.centered-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
  }

.transparent-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #fff; /* Fix for IE6-9 */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  width: 48%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 91%;
  }

.transparent-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  }

.large-btns_nav {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000 url("http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.gif") no-repeat left 50%;
  width: 38px;
  }

.large-btns_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  }

.large-btns_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right 50%;
  right: 0;
  }

.centered-btns_nav:focus,
.transparent-btns_nav:focus,
.large-btns_nav:focus {
  outline: none;
  }

.centered-btns_tabs,
.transparent-btns_tabs,
.large-btns_tabs {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  }

.centered-btns_tabs li,
.transparent-btns_tabs li,
.large-btns_tabs li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  _float: left;
  *float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  }

.centered-btns_tabs a,
.transparent-btns_tabs a,
.large-btns_tabs a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  display: inline-block;
  _display: block;
  *display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  }

.centered-btns_here a,
.transparent-btns_here a,
.large-btns_here a {
  background: #222;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ResponsiveSlides.js/1.53/responsiveslides.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ResponsiveSlides.js/1.53/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<div class="rslides_container">
  <ul class="rslides rslides1 centered-btns centered-btns1">
    <li>
      <img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://cdnparap110.paragonrels.com/ParagonImages/Property/P11/VALLEYMLS/480490/0/0/0/f479a2d775fa69c1118b25a3c2c8ecab/2/52ab9841b1e470e3517c5cdc93691ff5/480490.JPG" alt=''>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```